# CoreData: Sorting data using relationship between two table [entities]

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to sort a list of games based on the displayOrder, which is an attribute of categories.  Where categories are the name of the relationship between GAME and GCatogory entities.
This is the GCategory entity which has a to-many relation with the Game entity.
[image]

This is the Game entity which is the list of games which needs to be sorted based on the displayorder of the GCategory entity.
[image]

I have tried NSSortDescriptor and NSPredicate but I'm getting the following exception
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `categories` relationship on the `Game` entity to-many?  That would explain the error - how can CoreData sort Games by the displayOrder of the category, if Games have multiple categories?

Comment: Thanks, @pbasdf, for your response, can you suggest any workaround for the same, will making categories "to-one" relationship will help solve the problem?

Comment: Making it to-one should help.  But only if that models your data correctly.  The question is, can Games belong to more than one Category?  If so, you need to keep a to-many relation, but to think again about your desired sorting.